# Why is my code in an endless loop for the shape "rectangle"?

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printTriangles(){
int length;
int width;
int base;
}


void printRectangles(){
int length;
int width;
int base;
string shape;
string repeat;
if ("rectangle" == shape)
{
    cout << "Enter the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> width;
}
if ("Rectangle" == shape)
{
    cout << "Enter the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> width;
}
for (int row = 1; row <= width; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= length; col++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

}
void printSquares(){
int length;
int width;
int base;
}


int main ()
{
int length;
int width;
int base;
string shape;
string repeat;

cout << "I will print squares for you!"<< endl << "Rectangles and triangles, too!"<< endl << endl;

cout << "Enter the shape that you would like to print (rectangle, triangle,  or square): ";
cin >> shape;

if ("rectangle" == shape)
printRectangles();
return 0;
}
```

When I enter in Rectangle, the code goes in an endless loop of stars, I have been working on this for the past day and I have yet to figure out what I did wrong. I believed I called my "printRectangles();" function correctly, can someone tell me if I called it correctly.

Comment: I don't think using value of uninitialized non-static local variable is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do initialize non-static local variables before using their values.

Try this:

```
void printRectangles(){
    int length = 0; // initialize for in case the reading fails
    int width = 0;

    // This is a function for printing rectangle,
    // so no checking for "rectangle", which is impossible because the input is not passed here

    cout << "Enter the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> width;
    for (int row = 1; row <= width; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= length; col++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never initializing width or length. The blocks where they are entered by the user are guarded by an if-statement that will always evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

In function `printRectangles` variable `shape` is an empty string

```
void printRectangles(){
int length;
int width;
int base;
string shape;
^^^^^^^^^^^^       
//...
```

So the if statements

```
if ("rectangle" == shape)
{
//..
```

and

```
if ("Rectangle" == shape)
{
//...
```

will be executed never because the conditions evaluate to `false`.

Thus variables `length` and `width` will have indeterminate values and the loops

```
for (int row = 1; row <= width; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= length; col++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

do not make sense in this case.

Either do not check the shape in the function because the function can be called only for rectangles as for example

```
void printRectangles()
{
    int length;
    int width;

    cout << "Enter the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> width;

    for (int row = 1; row <= width; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= length; col++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Or declare the function as having a parameter that specifies the shape. As for example

```
void printRectangles( const std::string &shape );
```

and check the shape in the function.